# Compiling C++ for the JVM

Tags: java, c++, compiler-construction

When compiling C++ you of course use a compiler for the target platform you want to compile for. Is there a C++ compiler that targets the JVM (so instead of using the Java "native" interface C++ code is compiled to Java byte code)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421951/running-interpreting-c-on-top-of-the-jvm

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Virtual_Machine#C_to_bytecode_compilers

Comment: Are you asking this question because you have some C++ library you want to use from Java and you want to avoid using JNI? If so, keep in mind that if your C++ code uses platform specific libraries, you aren't going to be able to call those without using JNI...

Comment: @bwawok: Which JVM JIT compiler outputs C++?

Comment: @bwawok What do you mean JIT compiler compiles byte code to C++?

Comment: @KorayTugay I have no idea I wrote the comment 5 years ago, might want to look at a more recent post

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> [NestedVM](http://nestedvm.ibex.org/) provides binary translation for Java Bytecode. This is done by having GCC compile to a MIPS binary which is then translated to a Java class file. Hence any application written in C, C++, Fortran, or any other language supported by GCC can be run in 100% pure Java with no source changes.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to run a C or C++ program in the Java VM?

Comment: @TheLQ Maybe the OP was envious of C++/CLI?

Comment: I actually found this independently (I remembered something about GCC MIPS, and so I Googled "GCC MIPS JVM").  But in retrospect it's not surprising that it's already been in an answer on SO.

Comment: Really, the reason I was interested is that Mathematica 8 can now generate C from Mathematica code. I was interested in running code made in Mathematica inside of a Java program without using MathLink or some other technology that would require the end user to install extra software. Really, this whole idea is only conceptual for me. Source: http://awurl.com/FTlvm62ns

Comment: @TheLQ: `Why on earth would you want to run a C or C++ program in the Java VM?`. Well, for C++, having fully featured RAII on a JVM would be a good thing. And operator overloading. And, well, lambdas... :-D

Comment: And simply because Standard C++ code is portable on a host of platforms, including the CLR. (I'm not talking about libraries) The JVM seems to be Terra Incognita on that matter.

@chrisaycock: I'm not the OP but yes, I'm envious of C++/CLI :)

Comment: @ TheLQ the simple answer is that any working C or C++ code can be used on the JVM. Porting, rewrites, etc take time and money. A compiler with some tests is a better option in many cases. I could see it being useful with some legacy code issues too.

Comment: @TheLQ: "Why on earth would you want to run a C or C++ program in the Java VM?": For you I recommend think about "if all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail"; The answer is same reason why C/C++ is implemented for CLI,,,,,

Comment: @TheLQ because the VM can abstract the underlying CPU? If I have some C/C++ that I need to ship where I don't and can't know what CPU it will need to run on, requiring a JVM is likely both simpler for the user and easier for the developer to get right than trying to set up an end user build. -- Or consider the bootstrap problem: a C++ build requires a specific compiler regardless of host CPU. Having a copy of LLVM or GCC compiled to JVM checked into your repo would more or less solve that without ever knowing the list of host CPUs that need to be supported.

Answer (score 13):

As I have answerd on this similar [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37790144/1298461) there is a new kid in town called [gcc-bridge](https://github.com/bedatadriven/renjin/tree/master/tools/gcc-bridge). It's a maven plugin and supports all the gnu laguages like c, c++, fortran.